# How to make a 3-color gradient border with glowing effect like this in CSS?

Tags: css, border, gradient

[image]

AS you noticed the gradient will start from
light blue -> white -> dark blue
top to bottom and there's a glow effect

is this possible on CSS?

Comment: Yes, it's possible; where did you get stuck? Have you written any HTML, attempted any CSS? If so, please share your (**relevant**) "*[mcve]*" code in your question; ideally as a working [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/82548) (working meaning that it can be run using your posted code, in the question; we know it doesn't achieve your desired result but it's to let us see how far you've got and to allow us to easily reproduce your problem).

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Yes, it is indeed possible to create a gradient with a glow effect using CSS. You can get this by combining the `linear-gradient` property and the `box-shadow` property.

Here is an example:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #ffffff, #00008B);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.5); /* Adjust the color and spread as needed */
}

/* Add other styles for your content */
.content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

In this example:

- The `linear-gradient` property is used to create a gradient that goes from lightblue (`#87CEEB`) to white to dark blue(`#00008B`) from top to bottom.

Hope to be helpful for your coding.

PS: If you just want to give that effect on border you can do like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.border-container {
  width: 200px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  height: 200px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
  border-width: 20px; /* Adjust the border width as needed */
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #ffffff, #00008B) 1;
  border-image-slice: 20; /* Adjust the slice value to match the border width */
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.5); /* Adjust the shadow properties as needed */
}
```

Comment: Can I see it in snippet?